# python socket error: unable to select on socket

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I have a python class which includes a UDP socket. The socket initial code as below:

```
self.cs = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
self.cs.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
self.cs.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
self.cs.bind(('', 0))
```

and also I define functions which belong to the class and call the socket to send/ receive data. The code in functions as below:

```
with self.lock:
  while True:
    try:
      self.cs.sendto(packet, (self.host, 80))
      self.cs.settimeout(10)
      response = self.cs.recvfrom(1024)
      break
```

The whole class is designed in Singleton and be created by the main thread.
The program works fine at the beginning. Data can be send and received as normal.

However, after a while, about 1 hour later, the program gets error as "unable to select on socket" while it runs to the line, "response = self.cs.recvfrom(1024)".

I've googled for few days, but still have no clue why and how this error be triggered.

My python version is 2.7.13 and please help me to understand how to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CPython source code (written in C, hence the name) shows that message is produced from a function called `select_error`. That is called for `recvfrom` (`sock_recvfrom_guts`) like this:

```
...
if (!IS_SELECTABLE(s)) {
    select_error();
    return -1;
}
...
```

So that error message is only triggered when the macro `IS_SELECTABLE` returns a false value. The macro is defined here:

```
#ifdef HAVE_POLL
/* Instead of select(), we'll use poll() since poll() works on any fd. */
#define IS_SELECTABLE(s) 1
/* Can we call select() with this socket without a buffer overrun? */
#else
/* If there's no timeout left, we don't have to call select, so it's a safe,
 * little white lie. */
#define IS_SELECTABLE(s) (_PyIsSelectable_fd((s)->sock_fd) || (s)->sock_timeout <= 0.0)
#endif
```

From this we can deduce that your system doesn't have the `poll` facility (or at least it wasn't detected/configured when CPython was built); otherwise, `IS_SELECTABLE` would never fail. The `_PyIsSelectable_fd` call is the only consideration there (since we know that your `sock_timeout` is set to 10), and that is defined as:

```
/* A routine to check if a file descriptor can be select()-ed. */
#ifdef HAVE_SELECT
 #define _PyIsSelectable_fd(FD) (((FD) >= 0) && ((FD) < FD_SETSIZE))
#else
 #define _PyIsSelectable_fd(FD) (1)
#endif /* HAVE_SELECT */
```

That indicates to me that either the socket was closed somewhere along the way (which causes the `fd` to get set to `-1`) or the socket being checked has a file descriptor greater than or equal to `FD_SETSIZE`. `FD_SETSIZE` is platform-specific, but it's the largest file descriptor than can be used in the fixed-length file descriptor bit array processed by the `select` system call. On my linux platform, it's set to 1024. Could it be that you're inadvertently creating the socket over and over somehow, and eventually you have so many open file descriptors that the new socket gets a file descriptor above `FD_SETSIZE`?

To find out exactly what's going on, I would trap the exception where you're seeing the error message and print out the value of `self.cs.fileno()`. That should tell you the file descriptor value at the time the error is being triggered.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation which indicates a direction for me to trace y issue. I do find out that my system create lots sockets more than I expect by the command, netstat -p udp, I would find out how could this happened and fix it.

Comment: @PhoenixWu Possibly, your class is not actually a singleton? The only other explanation I see is that something is causing `self.cs` to be re-instantiated. One easy way to find it is to (temporarily) remove the `setsockopt(...SO_REUSEADDR` call. Then a subsequent attempt to bind the socket will fail, leading to an exception, and the backtrace should show where it's happening.

Comment: Indeed, after I trace the whole process, I found out that the self.cs will be create over and over time. I do create a Singleton class for the first level class, however, this class will create the level 2 class and it seems it re-create again and again. I've modified the way to initial my first class and make sure it does not be called in many different location. So far, my program has run more than 3 days and everything goes well. Thanks everyone.